# Using the Root Test to Solve $\sum_{k=1}^\infty(\frac{k^{2}}{2^{k}})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty(\frac{k^{2}}{2^{k}})$

So I've taken the $kth$ root of the numerator and denominator and got:

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty(\frac{k^{\frac{2}{k}}}{2})$

$k^{\frac{2}{k}}$ as k approaches infinity.  What to do now?

Comment: The ratio test is easier to apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} k^{\frac{2}{k}}$$ 
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} e^{ \frac{2 \ln k}{k}} = 1$$

as the exponent tends to $0$ as $k \to \infty$ by L'Hospital's Rule.

Dividing by two, we get that the limit is $\frac{1}{2} < 1$ and thus the series converges by the root test.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer.  Very informative.

Comment: No problem glad to help

Answer (score 2):

$k^{2/k}\rightarrow 1$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$
So you get the term will approach to $1/2$ which is less than $1$.
So by root test you can conclude that this series is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

For the [Root Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test), one does not evaluate the sum of the roots of the summands.  That is for a series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty {a_k}$ one does ***not*** evaluate the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sqrt[k]{a_k}$.

Rather, one evaluates the limit

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{k\to \infty}\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}&=\lim_{k\to \infty}\sqrt[k]{\frac{k^2}{2^k}}\\\\
&=\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{k^{2/k}}{2}\\\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as the limit is less than $1$, the root test guarantees that the series converges.

Comment: This is great, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure Don.  -Mark